# How to get the ground truths and the corresponding scores while using ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, roc

I am new to Keras and I which to use a roc curve with my test dataset to assess the quality of my model (the model was done using the functional api and is identified as "`model`" in my code snippet).

I plan to use the ROC Curve (using roc_curve from scikit-learn).

Example :

```
fpr_keras, tpr_keras, thresholds_keras = roc_curve(y_true,y_scores)
```

In order to do this, as the documentation says, I need the true binary labels (`y_true` in the example) and the target scores (`y_scores` in the example).

But I do not know how to get all the true binary labels from the test `ImageDataGenerator` (`test_generator` (see below) returns a DirectoryIterator).

And I do not know how to get the corresponding target scores with the `model.predict_generator` (it returns an array the size of a batch)

Right now my code look like this (summarized) :

```py
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve

height=150
width=150
batch_size=16

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/test',
        target_size=(height, width),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')

y_pred_keras = model.predict_generator(test_generator,1).ravel()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get label values which you are using `test_generator.classes`. It gives all the labels that are used for the test. For more information you can have look on this [code](https://gist.github.com/RyanAkilos/3808c17f79e77c4117de35aa68447045). It shows an example to do confusion matrix evaluation with keras data `flow_from_directory`. Now you can use `y_pred_keras` and `y_pred_true` from `test_generator.classes` to create ROC curve.

Comment: I tried your link, I get an error ```expected activation_5 to have shape (5,) but got array with shape (2,)```. When I fix it by modifying the model another error arise : (on line 77) ```ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10, 190]```. Also ```test_generator.classes``` is an int so I cannot do something like : ``` fpr_keras, tpr_keras, thresholds_keras = roc_curve(test_generator.classes, y_pred) ```

Comment: Did you find a solution for creating the curve yet!? Thanks.